Relating discriminants of hyperelliptic curves to discriminants of their defining polynomials
Let $C$ be a hyperelliptic curve defined by an equation of the form
$$
C: y^2=f(x)
$$
where $f$ is a polynomial of prime degree $p\geq3$, over a complete field $K$ of residue characteristic $p$. Suppose that $f$ is irreducible over $K$ and construct the field extension $L=K(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $f$.
I am interested in computing the integral discriminant of the extension $L/K$, i.e. $\Delta(L/K)$, knowing the discriminant of the curve i.e. $\Delta(C)=\Delta(f)$.
It is well known that $\Delta(L/K)|\Delta(C)$, however, I wonder if there is any more refined information when $C$ is given by a minimal model over $K$. Some naive numerical experiments in the case of $C=E$, an elliptic curve, make me believe that $\Delta(L/K)=\Delta(C)$, whenever the equation of $C$ is given by a minimal model, is that true? And if so, why?
